# Make user settings available in req

Tags: sails.js, passport.js

I know that passport exposes the current user (I think using the 'passport' policy) in req.user. I want to do a similar thing for settings of a particular user, which are stored in a separate collection (so that they are available in req.settings). How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The serializeUser method is responsible for that https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport#sessions

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});
```

So instead of just serializing the `user.id` you could serialize the the settings, too:

```
 passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    var sessionUser = { _id: user._id, name: user.name, settings: [...] }
    done(null, sessionUser);
});
```

You might want to read [Safe to store complete user info in session with Sails.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39340609/safe-to-store-complete-user-info-in-session-with-sails-js/39344490#39344490)

Comment: Thanks. What I ended up doing: I populated the settings collection (user was associated to settings) in passport.deserializeUser().